# Getting a 401 status error whilst establishing a connection to Concourse API

Tags: concourse

At the moment, we are trying to get CI working in our labs..

we have just followed the instructions on the concourse website.

We are able to login properly and have setup `~/.flyrc` as recomended ion the concourse-ci.org and concoursetutorial.com websites.

We have noticed that most commands are returning with a 401 Unauthorized error.

We have gone ahead setup the audit logs https://concourse-ci.org/concourse-web.html#audit-logs

But it isn't clear where this writes to, help?

It is difficult at the moment to properly trace this. BTW this is our first exposure to concourse.

We would like to know why? and what we can do resolve this (to cross this huddle).

`fly -t rdb-ci set-team --team-name a-team  --local-user admin --github-org organization --verbose --print-table-headers --non-interactive`

```
2019/07/10 22:02:37 GET /api/v1/info HTTP/1.1
Host: ci.example.org
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip


2019/07/10 22:02:37 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 88
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2019 21:02:37 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.2
X-Concourse-Version: 5.3.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

{"version":"5.3.0","worker_version":"2.1","external_url":"https://ci.example.org"}

setting team: a-team

role owner:
  users:
  - local:admin

  groups:
  - github:organization

apply team configuration? [yN]: y
2019/07/10 22:02:53 PUT /api/v1/teams/a-team HTTP/1.1
Host: ci.example.org
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 71
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"auth":{"owner":{"groups":["github:organization"],"users":["local:admin"]}}}

2019/07/10 22:02:53 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 14
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2019 21:02:53 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.2
X-Concourse-Version: 5.3.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

not authorized
could not find a valid token.
logging in to team 'main'

2019/07/10 22:02:53 GET /api/v1/info HTTP/1.1
Host: ci.example.org
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip


could not reach the Concourse server called rdb-ci:

    Get https://ci.example.org/api/v1/info: x509: certificate is valid for www.example.org, not ci.example.org

is the targeted Concourse running? better go catch it lol
```

Comment: Your error is saying: "Get https://ci.example.org/api/v1/info: x509: certificate is valid for www.example.org, not ci.example.org" which means when you're targeting `rdb-ci` in your fly commands (i.e. `fly -t rdb-ci <command> <options...>`) it thinks that `https://ci.example.org` is the URL for your Concourse API. This is initially set when running [`fly target`](https://concourse-ci.org/fly.html#fly-login) and can be updated with [`fly edit-target`](https://concourse-ci.org/fly.html#fly-edit-target)...

Comment: If you can share the output of [`fly targets`](https://concourse-ci.org/fly.html#fly-targets) we can start to see what's misconfigured.